# How to toggle checkbox value in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I have an input type `checkbox` as follow:

```
const [is_checked,set_is_checked]= useState(false);

const toggle_payment = () => {
    set_is_checked(!is_checked);
    console.log(is_checked);
}


return(
    <div>
        <input checked={is_checked}  onChange={toggle_value} type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
)
```

**The problem**

This seems to work fine, But when I `console.log(is_checked)` it looks like it prints the previous value. I tried both `onChange` and `onClick` but got the same result. What confuses me is that the `checkbox` is getting checked / unchecked each time I click on the box, but the `console.log` prints different value than what expected to print, like when I check the box with the mouse click, the box got checked but the `console.log` prints `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the state update using the updater provided by useState hook is asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect and update but will trigger a re-render

i think that if you console.log() outside the function you might gonna see the changes of the is_checked

Comment: you can check this stackblitz i created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7jckhn
you'll see that if you console.log() the value outside the value is correct "outside Toggle Payment"

Comment: you could also do something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jchkmr
and put the logic inside the useEffect()

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way state management works in React.  A call to a state setter function (in this case `set_is_checked`) will update the value, but that updated value is available *on the next render*.  When you call `console.log` below `set_is_checked`, you are still referencing the old value prior to the state being set.